# Executing unknown number of parallel ajax calls based on data returned by a previous ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a built a php backend which returns a JSON object (effectively a 2D array, I can reference it as `json[0][0]` for example, I don't know why though, I did not parse the JSON object) of information(train number, days it runs on etc) on trains between two stations.

Now what I want to query the availability of each train. I already have the php script for that (which returns a JSON object as well, giving the availability of the specified date as well as the next 5 days.).

This availability php script requires some input which is present as the first element of every nested(wrong term to use ?) array eg : `json[0][0], json[1][0], json[2][0]` if 3 trains are returned

I want this information returned as a response to parallel ajax calls. In the end I want to create a table based on these responses. My problems are:

1. Since I don't know the number of trains which will returned before hand, hence the number of parallel ajax calls to be made, how do I code this portion ?
2. Best way to make parallel calls seems to be $.when, how do I use it in this problems ?

I have just begun coding the function, and have something like this, yes I am an utter novice with JS and jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("form").submit(function(){    
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      //type: "POST",
      url: "./trains_bw_stations.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: { source: $('input[name*="src"]').val(), destination: $('input[name*="dstn"]').val(), 
                day: $('input[name*="day"]').val(), month: $('input[name*="month"]').val(), cl: $('input[name*="cl"]').val()  }
    })
      .done(function(trains) {
        console.log(trains)
        var requests = [], allData = {};

        for (var i = 0; i < trains.length; i++) {
            console.log(trains[i][0]);
            requests.push($.ajax({
                url: './availability.php', 
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { 
                        day: $('input[name*="day"]').val(), month: $('input[name*="month"]').val(),lccp_trndtl: trains[i][0]  }
                // success: function(data) {
                //  console.log(data);
                //     allData[''+i] = data;

            }).done(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    allData[i] = data})
            );
        }

        $.when.apply(requests).then(function() {

            console.log(allData) // this is line 41

            }
            // all requests have completed
            // allData array now contains the data from all the requests
            // put your processing logic in here...
        });
    });
    });
    });
```

allData remains empty ! console output :

```
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost/irl_poster/trains_bw_stations.php?source=ndls&destination=hyb&day=7&month=8&cl=SL". jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4
[Array[15], Array[15], Array[15]]
 ajaxRequests.js:19
12650NZM KCG YYYNYNYYA ajaxRequests.js:23
12724NDLSHYB YYYYYYYYA ajaxRequests.js:23
12722NZM HYB NYYYYYYYA ajaxRequests.js:23
Object {} ajaxRequests.js:41
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost/irl_poster/availability.php?day=7&month=8&lccp_trndtl=12650NZM+KCG+YYYNYNYYA". jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4
Object {0: Array[4], 2: Array[4], 4: Array[4], 6: Array[4], 8: Array[4], 10: Array[4]}
 ajaxRequests.js:34
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost/irl_poster/availability.php?day=7&month=8&lccp_trndtl=12724NDLSHYB+YYYYYYYYA". jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4
Object {0: Array[4], 2: Array[4], 4: Array[4], 6: Array[4], 8: Array[4], 10: Array[4]}
 ajaxRequests.js:34
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost/irl_poster/availability.php?day=7&month=8&lccp_trndtl=12722NZM+HYB+NYYYYYYYA". jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4
Object {0: Array[4], 2: Array[4], 4: Array[4], 6: Array[4], 8: Array[4], 10: Array[4]}
```

Comment: Where is the loop in your code which creates the requests?

Comment: Haven't written the loop yet, since it would just execute serially, wouldn't it ?

Comment: Thank you for editing my question, I'm writing the loop right now, will edit question in 5 minutes after including it, but it will just process the requests one at a time right?

Comment: No problem. No, they will be all executed simulatenously.

Comment: so even though the requests will be fired serially, a request won't wait for the previous one to finish, is that what you mean by simultaneously ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your `$.when.apply` call - it needs an initial context parameter, typically `$`

Your code also suffers the common problem of using the loop variable `i` from inside an asynchronous callback at which point it no longer retains its original value and the results all end up in `allData[trains.length + 1]`

So, instead of trying to accumulate `allData[i]` in the `.done` callback  you can remove that `.done` call altogether, and then within the `.when().then()` callback you can use the `arguments` array to access the individual results, which will automatically appear in the correct order:

```
$.when.apply($, requests).then(function() {

    // convert the arguments array, where each argument is in the form
    // [data, textStatus, jqXHR], into an array of just the data values
    var allData = [].map.call(arguments, function(arg) {
        return arg[0];
    });

    ...
});
```

The initial request loop can also be slightly simplified using `Array.prototype.map`:

```
var requests = trains.map(function(train) {
    // no "i" variable needed - use "train" instead of "train[i]"
    return $.ajax({
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Much better answer than mine, +1.

Comment: thanks guys, will try this solution. JS is making me feel like an idiot. I don't know why or how this works! Need to study up on it I guess.

Comment: @EagerNoob any bit in particular that needs explaining?  `map` is used to transform an array into a new array by passing each element through the supplied function.  The `[].map.apply(arguments, ...)` bit is used because `arguments` only _looks_ like an array (aka a "pseudo array") but actually isn't one, otherwise you could call `arguments.map(...)`

Comment: getting undefined is not a function on `var allData = [].map.apply(arguments, function(arg)` right now

Comment: what is in arguments anyway, where does it get initialized?

Comment: It's an automatic (psuedo)array that contains all of the arguments that were supplied to the current function.

Comment: you used an anonymous function, so it isn't undefined right ?

Comment: strange - I'm having the same problem with `.map.apply` - I've updated the code to fix it.

Comment: Ah, stupid error - I should have used `[].map.call` instead of `[].map.apply` in the original answer - updated again.

Comment: thank you, working as intended, `allData` is now an array of objects. How does the fix work ?. EDIT: ok, the previous answer worked to (the one with slice), but this looks more concise so, editing my code.

Comment: Some of the requests return blank array [] sometimes, I guess I'll need to resend the request in that case,  how do I handle this? or should I handle this in the php script ? return error code, and then write .fail() portion to resend request ?

Comment: It would be better to fix the system so it doesn't send back blank arrays... ;-)   Using `.fail` would be problematic because `$.when` will only work if _all_ the promises are resolved.

Comment: thank you very much. This question can be closed now I guess :D

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you need to use `$.when`, although your syntax is a little off. Try this:

```
.done(function(json) {
    var requests = [], allData = [];

    // loop over your result, amend as needed
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        requests.push($.ajax({
            url: 'foo.html', // build as needed using properties of json
            success: function(data) {
                allData.push(data);
            }
        }));
    }

    $.when.apply(requests).then(function() {
        // all requests have completed
        // allData array now contains the data from all the requests
        // put your processing logic in here...
    });
});
```

---

If you need to maintain the order of the data received, you could change the `allData` variable to an object, keyed by the index of the loop:

```
// note: amended lines only
var requests = [], allData = {};

success: function(data) {
    allData[i] = data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jquery and JS are kind of confusing, googling giver you so many different sources with so many different ways to do the same thing, more so in JS and jquery than other technologies it seems., i was wrting teh loop more like:

Comment: looks like this is what I need, will try it and let you know

Comment: @EagerNoob: Note the data array will be populated in the order the calls return, not the calling order, so you may need to add additional information if you need them in sequence.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie good point. OP, see my update if you need to maintain the order of requests within the `$.when` callback.

Comment: the order is indeed very important as it will count during the construction of the table! thanks for pointing it out. So now each allData[i] will contain a JSON obeject..so to access a specific field of data I will do something like allData[0][0][0](first field of data), right ?

Comment: The key of an object must be a string, so it would be: `allData['0'][0][0](first field of data)`, but yes that would work in theory.

Comment: trouble with populating allData, it remains empty it seems, I am getting the response in data variable though

Comment: It seems that `allData[i] = data` is executing after the instructions inside `$.when()`

Comment: I'm not getting the intended result, allData is empty even though data is being returned !!, editing question with teh latest code im using, with the console output

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan your order maintenance code won't work as it - `i` is a bound loop variable that will have the wrong value by the time the callback is invoked.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it's better not to even accumulate at that point of the code at all, per my answer.